# .NET analog of the CfSetInSyncState() Win32 function?

Tags: .net, winapi, uwp, marshalling, storagefile

Are there .NET analog for [CfSetInSyncState()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfsetinsyncstate) cloud files Win32 function? I looked through the .NET UWP Windows.Storage namespace but do not see anything similar.

Or at least can I get a safe file handle from [StorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile) .NET class (required for CfSetInSyncState() call), instead of calling
[CfOpenFileWithOplock()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfopenfilewithoplock) and [CfCloseHandle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfclosehandle) Win32 functions?

Comment: It's not obvious, what you are trying to accomplish. If all you want is to access a native Win32 API from your C# code, a straight-forward approach would be to wrap your native code in a Windows Runtime Component, and consume that component from C#.

Comment: I just do not want to reinvent the wheel. If there is a .NET API for this I would prefer to use it. And I see that at least partially it exists in Windows.Storage namespace, but for some reason not all functions are implemented.